# IdentityServer4 invalid grant. Detailed information

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, refresh-token

I see "invalid grant" responses on some refresh_token grant type requests. How can I see detailed information about the reason of "invalid grant". What is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Once your system is configured correctly there is only one reason why this should occur: when the refresh token expires. Therefore it is used in production code to determine 'end of session'.

A common reason might be a user leaving their UI running overnight and then experiencing a 401 when calling an API, followed by 'invalid_grant' when trying to refresh the token.

This should be handled gracefully, via an authorization redirect to ask the user to re-authenticate. Here is [some example code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/plumbing/oauth/AuthenticatorImpl.kt#L325) from a mobile sample of mine.